# jQuery Infinite (Loop)

Tags: jquery, loops, scroll, infinite

I've found plenty of documentation on infinite loops, but with multiple approaches and nothing that really EXPLAINS it, making it difficult to implement to my code.

I'm looking to use it in two ways:

1. horizontal scrolling (click arrow and animate)

http://jsfiddle.net/stfzy/33/ (currently I've got it to stop when it reaches end)

1. automatic loop of just one div, similar to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/UHpbR/2/

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.seqfx = function() {
        var elements = this,
            l = elements.length,
            i = 0;

        function execute() {
            var current = $(elements[i]);
            i = (i + 1) % l;

            current
                .fadeIn(400)
                .delay(4000)
                .fadeOut(300, execute);
        }
        execute();
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));

$("#fader div").seqfx();
```

Regardless of what the best solution is (i.e. is the stuff above any good or is there a simpler way?), if someone can explain the pieces or direct me to documentation that does, it'd be really great. I'd like to understand WHY the code is getting it to loop, not just copy/paste.

Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "infinite loop" is due to recursion in the call to `execute()`:

```
.fadeOut(300, execute);
```

This means that fadeOut will call `execute()` once the element has faded, meaning that `execute()` essentially calls itself again.

Comment: this does not work / is not stable. I wish it wasn't so, though.

Answer (score 1):

Is that a question: "i.e. is the stuff above any good or is there a simpler way?"

The answer is Yes, there is a much simpler way.
Just use that funky [plugin jquery-timing](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/).
It allows concatenation of animations and asynchronous actions in so many easy ways.

With jquery-timing you don't need to define seqfx. All you write is:

```
$("#fader div").repeat().each($).fadeIn(400).delay(4000).fadeOut(300,$);
```

Your jQuery method chain will then turn into something more timing-aware. The jQuery founder, John Resig, said that the plugin takes chaining to the next level.

So why is that code above the same infinite loop as with your seqfx?

The .repeat() method (without any .until()) will go on and on with the method chain behind. The .each($) starts a sequential loop, iterating all selected elements one by one. At last the version of fadeOut with .fadeOut(300,$) will just wait until the animation has finished.

So all that together animates all the selected elements one by one in an infinite loop.